# cordova 3.5 the plugin for analytics

Tags: cordova, google-analytics

i have installed on cordova 3.5 the plugin for analytics:
https://github.com/danwilson/google-analytics-plugin

Add to page:
analytics.startTrackerWithId('UA-XXXX-YY');
analytics.trackView('Screen Title');

Add to config.xml

My app uses webservices to get data

but on google dashboard nothing happens

Does anyone knows why?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to add this to your code:

```
window.analytics.setUserId('my-user-id');
```

and they should run OnDeviceReady...